# how to disable the particular log, dynamically in Nlog using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

I tried to disable the particular log in nlog config and I added like this

> logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" maxlevel="Trace" writeTo="t"
>   enabled="false"

is working fine. I need to programmatically in c#.

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this:

```
        // lookup for the rule in NLog config
        var rule = LogManager
            .Configuration
            .LoggingRules                
            .FirstOrDefault(_ => _.LoggerNamePattern == "*");

        // disable the rule
        if (rule != null)            
            rule.DisableLoggingForLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
```